# Laravel Request getting array of uploaded files

Tags: php, laravel

I have this input in my view:

```
<input type="file" name="slide[]">
<button type="button" ng-click="addSlide()">Add new</button>
```

Now I need to get the array of uploaded files but if I do:

```
dd($request->file('slide'));
```

It's only retrieving me the first one.

How can I access them?

Comment: Are you sure you append additional <input> tags correctly? The Laravel code is correct and will return multiple files if multiple files were successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `multiple` attribute to the file tag.

```
<input type="file" name="slide[]" multiple>
<button type="button" ng-click="addSlide()">Add new</button>
```